# Problema C++, verificar caracter de un string dentro de una estructura!

Tags: c++, string, struct

Cómo puedo lograr verificar que el sexo del corredor sea correspondiente a los caracteres 'H' o 'M', podría ocupar un do-while, pero lo que no sé es que si para la lectura y posterior verificacion debería ocupar competidor[i].sexo para verificar o se puede lograr mediante strncmp()?

Quiero saber como es posible verificar el caracter un string que esté dentro de una estructura, en este caso 'H' o 'M', hombre y mujer correspondientemente.

```
int main ()
{
    int cantidad_corredores, aux;
    char categoria[20];
    cout << "Cantidad de competidores: "; cin >> cantidad_corredores;
    
    struct corredor{ //Datos del corredor.
    char nombrePrimer[20];
    char apellidoPrimer[20];
    char apellidoSegundo[20];
    int  edad;
    char sexo[1];
    char club[20];
    }competidor[cantidad_corredores];

    //Entrada datos.
    for (int i = 0; i<cantidad_corredores; i++){
        fflush(stdin);
        cout << "Nombre: "; cin.getline(competidor[i].nombrePrimer, 20, '\n');
        cout << "Primer Apellido: "; cin.getline(competidor[i].apellidoPrimer, 20, '\n');
        cout << "Segundo Apellido: "; cin.getline(competidor[i].apellidoSegundo, 20, '\n');
        cout << "Edad: "; cin >> competidor[i].edad;
    //EN ESTA LINEA DESEO INTRODUCIR EL CARACTER QUE DEFINE EL SEXO DEL CORREDOR, H = HOMBRE, M = MUJER, Cómo lo logro?
        do{
        }while();//???
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Club: "; cin.getline(competidor[i].club, 20, '\n');
    }
        
    //Salida de datos.
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad_corredores; i++){
        cout << i << endl;
        cout << "Nombre corredor: " << competidor[i].nombrePrimer << endl;
        cout << "Primer apellido: " << competidor[i].apellidoPrimer << endl;
        cout << "Segundo apelllido: " << competidor[i].apellidoSegundo << endl;
        cout << "Edad: " << competidor[i].edad << endl;
        cout << "Sexo: " << competidor[i].sexo << endl;
        cout << "Club: " << competidor[i].club << endl;
        cout << "Categoria :" << categoria[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < cantidad_corredores; j++){
                if (competidor[i].edad<18){ //Juvenil
                    strcpy(categoria, "Juvenil");
                    cout << categoria << endl;
                }
                else {
                    if (competidor[i].edad<=40){ //Senior
                        strcpy(categoria, "Senior");
                        cout << categoria << endl;
                    }
                    else { //Veterano
                        strcpy(categoria, "Veterano");
                        cout << categoria << endl;
                    }
                }
        cout << endl;
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No puedes crear una formación cuyo tamaño sea una variable, en tu caso no se sabe el tamaño de la formación `competidor` porque `cantidad_corredores` se conoce sólo en tiempo de compilación.

Comment: En realidad si se puede, pero no deberías. Si querés que el programa sea portable no lo hagas. No todos los compiladores soportan VLA (variable length arrays).

Answer (score 2):

Para verificar si un carácter es igual a otro, basta con usar el operador de comparación:

```
bool es_H = competidor[i].sexo[0] == 'H';
```

Si `competidor[i].sexo[0]` es la letra hache mayúscula, la variable `es_H` tendrá valor verdadero (`true`), puedes usarlo en un `if`:

```
if (competidor[i].sexo[0] == 'H')
{
    // Código si sexo es H
}
else if (competidor[i].sexo[0] == 'M')
{
    // Código si sexo es M
}
```

Aunque también puedes usar un `switch` para cubrir más casos:

```
switch (competidor[i].sexo[0])
{
case 'H':
case 'h':
    // Código si sexo es H
    break;
case 'M':
case 'm':
    // Código si sexo es M
    break;
}
```

También puedes definir un operador de comparación en la estructura:

```
struct corredor{ //Datos del corredor.
    char nombrePrimer[20];
    char apellidoPrimer[20];
    char apellidoSegundo[20];
    int  edad;
    char sexo[1];
    char club[20];

    bool operator==(char c) const
    {
        return sexo[0] == c;
    }
}
```

Hecho eso podrás hacer la comparación de la siguiente manera:

```
if (competidor[i] == 'H' || competidor[i] == 'h')
{
    // Código si sexo es H
}
else if (competidor[i] == 'M' || competidor[i] == 'm')
{
    // Código si sexo es M
}
```

Si la variable `corredor::sexo` sólo va a contener un valor, no te compliques creando una formación de un elemento:

```
struct corredor{ //Datos del corredor.
    char nombrePrimer[20];
    char apellidoPrimer[20];
    char apellidoSegundo[20];
    int  edad;
    char sexo; // No hace falta que sea una formación
    char club[20];

    bool operator==(char c) const
    {
        return sexo == c;
    }
}
```

Comment: qué es c, en char c y sexo == c;

Comment: El `char c` en el operador de comparación `bool operator==` es el carácter (`char`) que pongas a la derecha de la comparación (operador `==`) cuando a la izquierda de la comparación (operador `==`) coloques una instancia de `corredor`.